# How to initialize QApplication with Qt Jambi within TeamCenter rich client

Tags: java, eclipse, qt-jambi, teamcenter, teamcenter-rac

1. I could run the "HelloWorld1" Qt-Jambi application with GUI as standalone.
2. I could run the "HelloWorld2" teamcenter-plugin (via Eclipse) inherited ViewPart.
3. Trying to init `QApplication` within plugin like below:

   public class MyComView extends ViewPart
   {
   static
   {
   //try to init Qt-Jambi
   //
   System.out.println("QQ==before load qtjambi");
   //
   QApplication qap1 = QApplication.instance();
   //
   System.out.println("QQ==after get instance");
   }
   //...
   }

My code is quite good compiled and linked.
But I have a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` error with below stacktrace:

```
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/trolltech/qt/gui/QApplication
    at com.mycom.myview.views.MyComView.<clinit>(MyComView.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:874)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.ViewDescriptor.createView(ViewDescriptor.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPartHelper(ViewReference.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.showView(Perspective.java:2228)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyShowView(WorkbenchPage.java:1067)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$20.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3816)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showView(WorkbenchPage.java:3813)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showView(WorkbenchPage.java:3789)
    at com.cals.testplugin2.handlers.CallMyViewPart.execute(CallMyViewPart.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(CommandContributionItem.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.access$10(CommandContributionItem.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem$5.handleEvent(CommandContributionItem.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3880)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3473)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.teamcenter.rac.aifrcp.Application.runApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamcenter.rac.aifrcp.Application.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1287)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.trolltech.qt.gui.QApplication
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:105)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    ... 59 more
```

What did I do wrong? How do I properly use Qt-Jambi within Eclipse-RCP, especially within a Teamcenter plugin?

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` can be thrown for several reasons. The code compiles nicely, but throws that exception during runtime.

If you run it from the command-line within a `.jar` file, then it could be that it not listed in the manifest of the jar file.

If you run it with in Eclipse, check your classpaths, or make sure the class can be found in working directory.

`com/trolltech/qt/gui/QApplication` depends on native libary code, so make sure you have the Qt Jambi native libs with your classpath or working directory.